# Creating a a link based on JSON property

Tags: c#, json, angularjs

I get a JSON serialized string to be displayed in UI . I want to show a particular property as hyperlink based on some parameters. What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-href`

[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

```
<a ng-href="{{valueFromController}}">link</a>
```

In your Angular Controller,

```
$scope.valueFromController = "https://www.google.com"; // change the value according to your conditions.
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-href` (see documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref))

You define a link in your html markup like this

```
<a ng-href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{yourJsonObject.property}}">link1</a>
```

where `yourJsonObject` is a javascript object in your $scope